# Recalling previous user's information for form autofill

Tags: database, forms, session, session-cookies

I have this form a user completes and their information is transferred to the next landing page's form for lead generation so they don't have to refill another form.

is there anyway to have the database dynamically create links so if the user leaves the landing page and clicks the link they will be directed to the landing page with all form filled information filled out how it was before?

this is the code that calls on the data

```
global $wpdb;

if ($_SESSION['form'] == 'old') {

$FirstName = $_REQUEST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_REQUEST['LastName'];
$Address1 = $_REQUEST['Address1'];
$Email = $_REQUEST['Email'];
} 
else {
$FirstName = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
$LastName = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
$Address1 = $_REQUEST['street'];
$Email = $_REQUEST['form_email'];
}



$_SESSION['FirstName'] = $FirstName;
$_SESSION['LastName'] = $LastName;
$_SESSION['Address1'] = $Address1;
$_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
```

then the form echos in the fields required